# why the static is used rather normal declaration?

Tags: c

**just a doubt.
what is static vs final?**
*this is the code for sum of two elements in an array equals target.*

```
   int *twoSum(int numbers[], int n, int target)
        {

            int temp = 0;
            int i = 0,j;

            //here i cant understand ,why the static is used rather normal declaration.
            static int result[2];

            for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for(j = i+1; j < n; j++)
                {
                    if(numbers[i]+numbers[j] == target)
                    {
                        result[0] = i ;
                        result[1] = j ;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Explicit lack of effort in creating this question.

Comment: @marcusshep not necessarily, but a little more words would have been nice. I **guess** the OP only knows the use of `static` for a function-scoped variable if the function needs to find the old value when called again, which isn't the case here. So a complete explanation what `static` **really** means should answer this question.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I would argue that a good question wouldn't leave the "answerer" guessing about the specifics of the question. Clearly this was copy/pasted, formatted then submitted. No signs of research or effort or understanding of the topic at hand. No "thanks for your time" or "I expected x and got y" absolutely nothing that shows an "asker" who is engaged in the process.

Comment: @marcusshep As I said (and I didn't ever say this was a **good** question) -- some more words would have been nice. But I'm only guessing about **why** OP doesn't understand this usage of static. It's still clear what the question is. Yes, it's a poor question.

Comment: BTW, this is a terrible algorithm for solving this problem. Try to come up with something asymptotically faster, at least `n logn` instead of the quadratic solution you came up with.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are tutorials and even courses/teachers telling something like "use static if you need the old value again next time you call the function" without explaining what `static` really means, so I'm quite confident in my guess ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`static` is a *storage class specifier* and its main effect is to specify the *storage duration* of the object. *static storage duration* means the variable lives for the whole execution time of the program.

In contrast, without *static*, a variable in a function scope (in general: not in the file scope) defaults to *automatic storage duration*, which means it only lives as long as the execution is inside of its scope, so it doesn't **exist** any more once you return from the function. You could never return a pointer to this array if it wasn't `static` -- the variable would be gone (and the pointer returned would therefore be invalid)!

Keep in mind that this code changes **the same** variable on each invocation, so it is for example not thread safe (two threads could attempt to change this same variable at the same time).

Answer (score 1):

using `static` keyword changes the *storage class* of the variable, from local (auto) - which means variable is destroyed at end of scope, to static - which means variable lifetime starts at the start of the program and ends when it "dies".

Since local variables are destroyed at end of scope, returning a local array from a function would result in **Undefined-Behavior**, but `static` makes sure the variable will outlive it's scope, making it safe to return it.

Another 2 things to note while using `static`:

1. `result` is the **same** variable even in different invocations, unlike local variables
2. `result` (the whole array) is initialized to 0

Comment: while this is correct in general, it isn't the reason for `static` in the code shown.

Comment: Indeed. thx for the remark :)

Comment: nitpick: "*variable lifetime starts at first invocation of the function*" <- it starts as soon as the program runs, but that's no difference in practice, because when it's in function scope, there's no way to access it before the function is called the first time.

Comment: thanks for the answer and sorry for the question framing.i dont know how to use stack overflow ,sorry.